# What qualities are needed for a function to preserve inequality?

Tags: inequality

If $a<b$,  what qualities of $f(x)$ are needed to be certain that
$f(a) < f(b)$ ?
For example, is it enough to say that $f(x)$ is monotonic and positive?

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing monotonicity with the fact that if the derivative is positive, then the function is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need this for all $a$ and $b$ then by definition $f$ is strictly increasing. Being positive is not relevant.